# rtrim anything starting with a specific set of characters

Tags: php, trim, character-trimming

Sorry I don't have any code to post to be discussed, it's one simple question

How to `rtrim` a string beginning from a set of characters?

String: abcde**fghijk**

What to remove: **fghijk**

Anything at the end of the string that starts (the part to be removed) with **fg**

So, if we have dpgjsufgpeiz, remove **fgpeiz**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> If TRUE, strstr() returns the part of the haystack before the first occurrence of the needle (excluding the needle).

```
$whatwewant = strstr($input, 'fg', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `preg_replace` to achieve the desired output:

```
$output = preg_replace('/fghijk$/s', '', 'abcdefghijk');
```

Comment: `Anything at the end of the string that starts (the part to be removed) with fg`

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `preg_replace`

```
$str = 'dpgjsufgpeiz'
$str = preg_replace('/fg\w*$/', '', $str);
```

[Test online](https://regex101.com/r/LbkgS7/1)